# Simulating unfair dice with java/R (programming done)

Tags: java, r, probability, probability-theory

Task : Unfair die(6 sides) is being rolled n times. Probability of 1 is p1, probability of 2 is p2 and so on. Write a computer program, that for given n (n<100), the probability of set (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6) and $x \in [n,600n]$ would find the probability of sum of dice values is less than x. Program cannot work more than 5 minutes. This is an extra question that will give me extra points, but so far nobody has done it. I quess beginner computer scientist like me can learn from this code also, since i found 0 help with bias dice in the web and came up with roulette like solution. I kind of wanted to show the world my way also.

I have 2 solutions - using geometrical and statistical probability.

My question is: 1) Is it correct when i do it like this or am i going wrong somewhere ? 
2) Which one you think gives me better answer geometric or statistical probability ? 
My intuition says it is geometric, because it is more reliable. 
i think it is correct answer that my code is giving me - more than 0.99..... usually.
I wanted somebody to check my work since i'm not sure at all and i wanted to share this code with others.

I prefer Java more since it is much faster than R with loops, but i gave R code also for statistical , they are very similar i hope it is not a problam.

Java code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Statistical_prob_lisayl2_geometrical {

    public static double mean(ArrayList<Double> a) {
        double sum=0;
        int len = a.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sum = sum + a.get(i);
        }
        return (sum/len);
    }

    public static double geom_prob(double p1,double p2,double p3,double p4,double p5,double p6){
        ArrayList<Double> prob_values = new ArrayList<Double>();

        int repeatcount = 1000000;
        int[] options = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int n = 50;
        double[] probabilities = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6};
        for (int i = 0 ; i < repeatcount ; i++ ) { // a lot of repeats for better statistical probability
            int sum = 0; //for each repeat, the sum is being computed
            for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++ ) { // for each repeat there is n cast of dies and we compute them here
                double probability_value=0; // the value we start looking from with probability
                double instant_probability = Math.random(); // we generate random probability for dice value
                    for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++ ) { // because we have 6 sides, we start looking at each probability like a roulette table
                        probability_value = probability_value + probabilities[k]; // we sum the probabilities for checking in which section the probability belongs to
                        if (probability_value>instant_probability) {
                            sum = sum + options[k]; // if probability belongs to certain area , lets say p3 to p4, then p3 is added to sum
                                break; // we break the loop , because it would give us false values otherwise
                        }
                    }
                }
            double length1 = (600*n)-n-(sum-n); //length of possible x values minus length of sum
            double length2 = 600*n-n;
            prob_values.add( (length1/length2) ); // geometric probability l1/l2

            }
        return mean(prob_values); // we give the mean value of a arraylist, with 1000000 numbers in it
    }
    public static double stat_prob(double p1,double p2,double p3,double p4,double p5,double p6){
        ArrayList<Double> prob_values = new ArrayList<Double>();

        int repeatcount = 1000000;
        int[] options = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int n = 50;
        double[] probabilities = {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6};
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < repeatcount ; i++ ) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++ ) {
                double probability_value=0;
                double instant_probability = Math.random();
                    for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++ ) {
                        probability_value = probability_value + probabilities[k];
                        if (probability_value>instant_probability) {
                            sum = sum + options[k];
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            int x = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*(600*n-n)+n);
            if( x>sum ) {
                count = count + 1;  
            }
        }
        double probability = (double)count/(double)repeatcount;
        return probability;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(stat_prob(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3));
        System.out.println(geom_prob(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3)); 
    }

}
```

R code:

```
repeatcount = 100000
options = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
n = 50
probabilities = c(1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,3/10,3/10)

count = 0
for (i in 1:repeatcount) {
sum = 0
for (i in 1:n) {
    probability_value=0
    instant_probability = runif(1,0,1)
    for (k in 1:6){
        probability_value = probability_value + probabilities[k]
        if (probability_value>instant_probability) {
            sum = sum + options[k] 
            break
        }
        }
    }
    x = runif(1,n,600*n)
    x
    sum
    if ( x> sum ) {
        count = count + 1   
    }
}
count
probability = count/repeatcount
probability
```

Comment: This can be vectorised in R. Take a look at ?rmultinom and ?replicate. For example: colSums(replicate(repeatcount, c(rmultinom(1, n, probabilities)) * 1:6)) gives you a vector of length repeatcount, where each element is a sum of n die-roll outcomes. It takes less than a second for n = 50 and repeatcount = 100000. You could then do a logical comparison of the vector against x, which could be a scalar or a vector of length n. Take the mean of that logical outcome and you have your proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do??

```
n <- 50     # number of rolls in a trial
k <- 100000 # number if trials in the simulation
x <- 220    # cutoff for calculating P(X<x)
p <- c(1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,3/10,3/10) # distribution of p-side
X <- sapply(1:k,function(i)sum(sample(1:6,n,replace=T,prob=p)))
P <- sum(X<x)/length(X)    # probability that X < x

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(X)
plot(quantile(X,probs=seq(0,1,.01)),seq(0,1,.01),type="l",xlab="x",ylab="P(X < x)")
lines(c(x,x,0),c(0,P,P),col="red",lty=2)
```

[image]

This makes sense because the expected side

```
E(s) = 1*0.1 + 2*0.1 + 3*0.1 + 4*0.1 + 5*0.3 + 6*0.3 = 4.3
```

Since you are simulating 50 rolls, the expected value of the total should be 50*4.3, or about 215, which is almost exactly what it is.

The slow step, below, runs in about 3.5s on my system. Obviously the actual time will depend on the number of trials in the simulation, and the speed of your computer, but 5 min is absurd...

```
system.time(X <- sapply(1:k,function(i)sum(sample(1:6,n,replace=T,prob=p))))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.20    0.00    3.24
```

Comment: I think you wrongly understand the question. 

We have to get the probability that X is less than x , but x is random number between [n,600n], so if X values are around 190-200, x values range from 50 to 30000, your approach gave me probability 0.644, i think that it is kind of small.

Comment: Oh yeah , the x is fixed value , you are correct like this yes, i calculated different probability.